# Exporting images from Illustrator/Photoshop for the web

Tags: image, png, jpeg, photoshop

What’s the best way to export PNGs or JPEGs for the web that have been created in Illustrator and/or Photoshop?

Sometimes they’re vector only, sometimes they’re raster images, sometimes they are a mixture of both. My images always end up blurry when uploaded onto the web especially when viewed at less than or more than 100% in a browser.

What are the exact options I should be selecting?

Comment: Seems this may be a bit too open ended a question for stack overflow. Maybe change the question from asking for the "best" way to something less subjective, like "What's an advisable way to export... and why"? Still may be too open ended though. We'll see.

Comment: -- Confused on how a single image can be a mixture of both vector and raster components?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for for the web are .svg or scalable vector graphics. Png and jpg are pixel based and regardless of how you save them from photoshop or illustrator, these formats retain information as pixel data. To be able to scale effectively with the web, you need a vector format. .eps and .pdf are two common ones for printing, and have been used on the web, however the .svg format is becoming more of a standard.